# Cognito and API Gateway closest region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

In order for a given user to login using Cognito, using the aws-sdk I need to perform a request to a specific region, i.e.

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: 'eu-west-1:id',
  Logins: {
    'accounts.google.com': idToken
  }
});
```

Let say that I have 2 Cognito pools: one in USA and one in EU. What I would like to do is to send this request to the nearest Cognito region.

I have the same problem when sending requests to API Gateway. The signed signature must be created using the region. (I'm actually using the API automatically generated SDK which does this for me)

```
const api = apigClientFactory.newClient({
  accessKey: AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId,
  secretKey: AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey,
  sessionToken: AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken,
  region: AWS.config.region
});
```

It looks like AWS forces me to know the region I want to connect on the frontend. Because the frontend is just one distributed with CloudFront, what is the best way to do all this?

The only solution I've came up with is to have:

- One s3 bucket per region that includes the deployed version of the app with the region info
- One cloudfront distribution per s3 bucket
- Redirect to the nearest cloudfront distribution using latency or geo routing with Route53.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For API Gateway, it is not currently possible to set-up any kind of automatic routing to the nearest region.  This is a commonly requested feature and it is on our backlog to be implemented eventually.  For now, you can either build region selection logic into the client application or distributed different versions of your client to different regions.